# I want to alter bneExample.s so that it outputs the largest of the three register values

Tags: mips

So far I've only been able to store my third value in a register but not sure how to edit my logic to do another comparison after comparing the first two stored values. Basically I want stuff: .word 42, 666, 777 to return 777 in the terminal because it is larger that 42, and 666. I have done the logic to compare 42 & 666 and output 666 to the terminal.

```
    #       Embarrassingly written by Gary
    .data
    .align  2
    stuff: .word 42, 666, 777 
    .text
    .globl main       
    main:   la      $s0, stuff
    lw      $s2, 0($s0)     # put first value in s1
    lw      $s3, 4($s0)     # put second value in s2
    lw      $s4, 4($s0)     # put third value in s3

    slt     $s1, $s2, $s3   # if ($s2 < $s3) $s1=1 else $s1 = 0
    bne     $s1, $zero, foo  
    li  $v0, 1 
    move    $a0, $s2 
    syscall                 # 4 print out the value in $s2
    j done 
    
    foo:    li  $v0, 1
    move    $a0, $s3
    syscall                 # print out the value in $s1

    done:   li      $v0, 10      
    syscall                 # TTFN
```

Erik has commented that my original question is flawed. Here is a new update showing the logic behind what I am trying to do. How do I translate this logic into a working MIPS program?

```
    #       Embarrassingly written by Gary
    .data
   .align  2
    stuff: .word 42, 666, 777 
    .text
    .globl main       
    main:   la      $s0, stuff
    lw      $s2, 0($s0)     # put first value in s1
    lw      $s3, 4($s0)     # put second value in s2
    lw      $s4, 4($s0)     # put third value in s3

    slt     $s1, $s2, $s3   # if ($s2 < $s3) $s1=1 else $s1 = 0
    slt     $s2, $s3, $s4   # if ($s3 < $s4) $s2=1 else $s2 = 0
    bne     $s1, $zero, foo
    bne     $s2, $zero, goo  
    li  $v0, 1 
    move    $a0, $s2 
    syscall                 # 4 print out the value in $s2
    j done 
    
    foo:    li  $v0, 1
    move    $a0, $s3
    syscall                 # print out the value in $s1
    goo:    li  $v0, 1
    move    $a0, $s4        # print out the value in $s3

    done:   li      $v0, 10      
    syscall                 # TTFN
```

Comment: This is a Q&A site, so, please ask a question.  (FYI, Can you help me doesn't count here. 
 You need to express what you've tried and where you're stuck, and ask an actual question.)

Comment: Can you do it in C?  If not, you need an algorithm, so search the web for "compare three numbers for largest"  A answer from duckduckgo is https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/examples/largest-number-three.  See example 3.  If you already can do it in C, then you need help translating that into assembly, but where are you stuck?

Comment: I'm not able to try this in C and then translate it into assembly. I'm supposed to write the algorithm in a MIPS assembly language simulator. I'm stuck after comparing the initial two register values. I see that 666 is greater than 42 using my slt $s1, $s2, $s3   # if ($s2 < $s3) $s1=1 else $s1 = 0 line of code. Must I make another slt line comparison that now compares $s3 & $s4? From there am I in need of an additional print statement or should my print logic return the new highest value? Thank you for the responses.

Comment: Have a look at the link I mentioned -- it outlines the logic very nicely.

Comment: I mostly understand the logic I suppose what you're trying to explain is that right now I'm unable to translate the logic I know into a MIPS program that works. I should be asking how to do this and not about the logic. I have edited my original code to include what I am trying to do. I have added slt  $s2, $s3, $s4 # if ($s3 < $s4) $s2=1 else $s2 = 0 under my original slt line. Then I added a new bne line calling goo, a copy of foo's logic: bne  $s2, $zero, goo. Finally introducing goo: goo: li $v0, 1
  move $a0, $s4  # print out the value in $s3. This is meant to replicate foo.

Comment: Quick note: s4 should come from 8(s0).

Answer (score 0):

Comparing the values s2 with s3 and s3 with s4 is a start.  But it is not sufficient.

You never compare s2 with s4, and, sometimes that is critical.  Let's take an example.

```
 s2   s3  s4  s2<s3   s3<s4
+---+---+---+-------+-------+
| 8 | 6 | 9 | false | true  |
+---+---+---+-------+-------+
| 8 | 6 | 7 | false | true  |
+---+---+---+-------+-------+
```

From those booleans you can't tell that in row 1 that s4=9 is the max and in row s2=8 is the max.

There's at least two ways to fix it:

Add another boolean s2 vs. s4 as shown here:

```
 s2   s3  s4  s2<s3   s3<s4   s2<s4
+---+---+---+-------+-------+-------+
| 8 | 6 | 9 | false | true  | true  |
+---+---+---+-------+-------+-------+
| 8 | 6 | 7 | false | true  | false |
+---+---+---+-------+-------+-------+
```

Now there's enough information to tell which one is the largest.  However, this will require some interpretation of 3 different booleans.

The other approach is shown in example #3.  Adapting to your code, in the case that s2 doesn't beat s3 then the next comparison is ***s3 vs. s4***.  However, if s2 does beat s3, then the next comparison is ***s2 vs. s4***.  Only two comparisons are done, but the 2nd comparison varies based on the result of the first one.  Can you follow the if-then-else logic in the C example to see that?

---

Nested statements in C are easy to translate into assembly.

An if-then-else has the pattern:

```
   if C-language-condition is false goto elsepart;
   then-part     // will happen if C-language-condition is true
   goto endif;   // skip the else-part since the then-part just fired
elsepart:
   else-part     // will happen if C-language-condition is false
endif:
```

When the then-part contains an if-then-else also, simply follow this same pattern template to generate the assembly  — then place the whole assembly fully in the then-part of the first, outer if-statement.  Be sure to use different label names for each template usage, and, the translation will be true.

```
   if C-language-condition is false goto elsepart1; // outer if, if#1
   //then-part1 consisting of if-then-else#2
   if C-language-condition is false goto elsepart2; // inner if, if#2
   then-part#2
   goto endif2;
elsepart2:
   else-part#2
endif2: // end of if#2
   // end of then-part1
   goto endif1;
elsepart1:
   else-part#1
endif1:
```

Can you see how the template pattern for if#2 simply nests within the then-part of if#1?

Stick to the pattern for translation.  Use new label names (e.g. different numbers for each usage of such a template.  Just like in C, when nested, nest one template expansion fully within the the appropriate body portion (then-part or else-part or loop body) of another outer statement.